# Sum the number of occurrence by id

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to COUNT the number of times a value occurs in a table, however, use the count of 1 if the value appears more than once for each id.

Take the below table as an example. We want to see if either {5,6} occurred for p_id. If more than 1 occurrence of {5,6} is found, treat it as 1. For eg. p_id 1, the total count is 1.

```
p_id        status
 1             5
 1             6
 1             2
 2             5
 2             5
 3             4
 3             2
 4             6
 4             2
 4             5
```

..transforms to..

```
p_id        count
 1             1          
 2             1
 3             0
 4             1
```

COUNT(CASE status IN (5,6) THEN 1 END) does an overall count.

Answer (score 2):

Use the `CASE...WHEN...` as follows:

```
SELECT a.id, ISNULL(b.cnt, 0)
FROM 
    (
        SELECT DISTINCT id FROM tab
    ) a
    LEFT JOIN 
    (
         SELECT id, CASE COUNT(*) WHEN 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END 'cnt' 
         FROM tab WHERE val in (5, 6) GROUP BY id
    ) b
   ON a.id = b.id
```

[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9752d/6)

Comment: The self-join is unnecessary if you use the COUNT(CASE(...)) the OP posted.

Answer (score 0):

This solution provides a quick setup and a simple two-step explanation of how I do this, using your example. The second query provides the desired result:

```
CREATE TABLE #temp (p_id INT, [status] INT); 
INSERT #temp VALUES (1,5);
INSERT #temp VALUES (1,6);
INSERT #temp VALUES (1,2);
INSERT #temp VALUES (2,5);
INSERT #temp VALUES (2,5);
INSERT #temp VALUES (3,4);
INSERT #temp VALUES (3,2);
INSERT #temp VALUES (4,6);
INSERT #temp VALUES (4,2);
INSERT #temp VALUES (4,5);

-- Simple two-step tutorial
-- First, group by p_id so that all p_id's will be shown 
-- run this to see...
SELECT A.p_id
FROM #temp A
GROUP BY A.p_id;

-- Now expand your query
-- Next, for each p_id row found, perform sub-query to see if 1 or more exist with status=5 or 6
SELECT A.p_id
    ,CASE WHEN EXISTS(SELECT 1 FROM #temp B WHERE B.p_id=A.p_id AND [status] IN (5,6)) THEN 1 ELSE 0 END AS [Count]
FROM #temp A
GROUP BY A.p_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the [SIGN()](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188420.aspx) function.  It is exactly what you are looking for.

```
SELECT
  [p_id],
  SIGN(COUNT(CASE WHEN [status] IN (5,6) THEN 1 END)) AS [count]
FROM #temp
GROUP BY p_id
```

Answer (score 0):

You can translate 5,6 = 1 and rest to 0 then do max()

```
with cte as (
  select p_id, case when status in (5,6) then 1 else 0 end status
  from FROM #tem)

select p_id, max(status) status
from cte
group by p_id
```